# PHP + Ajax, get fresh image from webcam

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, unix, webcam

I just can't seem to get this working on a Linux server. On WAMP this is working nicely.

Basically, I have set up a webcam, which uploads images every 60 seconds to a folder on FTP server. Then, I've created a site, where I call Ajax in order to scan this folder and get last image (based on creation time).

When I access the page, freshest image is indeed loaded, CHMOD are set correctly. But when I wait on the page, new ajax requests are called and returned image is always the same, eventhough there are new images already uploaded on FTP - those new images are skipped and no CHMOD are set either.

I don't know what is the issue.

This is what I have:

**index.php**:

```
<img id='webcam-img' alt='Webkamera' src='' />

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function getImage() {
    var src = '';
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax-get-webcam-image.php",
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
          src = data;
        }
    });
    return src;
}

function updateImage() {
    var src = getImage();
    $("#webcam-img").attr("src", src + "?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime());
    setTimeout(updateImage, 5000);
}

updateImage();
</script>
```

**ajax-get-webcam-image.php**:

```
<?php
$folder = "images/webcam"; // the folder with images

function getImages($dir) {
    $allFiles = scandir($dir);
    $files = array_diff($allFiles, array('.', '..'));
    foreach ($files as $f) {
        chmod($dir . '/' . $f, 0644); // uploaded images are set to 0640 and can't be read on a page. Must set CHMOD to 644
    }

    $ignored = array('.', '..');    // ignore this

    $files = array();
    foreach (scandir($dir) as $file) {
        if (in_array($file, $ignored)) continue;
        $files[$file] = fileatime($dir . '/' . $file);
    }

    $files = array_keys($files);    // sort images
    $files = array_reverse($files);

//     foreach ($files as $k => $file) {
//         if ($k > 9) {               // delete old images, leave 10 freshest on server
//             unlink(__DIR__ . '/' . $dir . '/' . $file);
//         }
//     }

    return ($files[0]) ? $files[0] : false; // return freshest image
}

$img = getImages($folder);

echo $folder . '/' . $img;
?>
```

Thanks for tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it was an issue with caching, so I've modified ajax call with adding `t=" + new Date().getTime()` to url parameter:

```
function getImage() {
    var src = '';
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax-get-webcam-image.php?t=" + new Date().getTime(),
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
          src = data;
        }
    });
    return src;
}
```